# Android reading pdf metadata - memory issue

Tags: java, android, pdf, metadata

I'm currently building an android application that displays a set of pdf files in a ListView. Instead of just displaying the filename I want to grab the Title from the metadata of the pdf and display that in the list, if the file doesnt have a Title set then just use the filename. I'm using iText atm, here is what I have:

```
File[] filteredFiles = root.listFiles(filter);
for (int i=0;i<filteredFiles.length;i++) {
    try {                   
        File f = filteredFiles[i];                  
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String title = reader.getInfo().get("Title");
        reader.close();

        //Do other stuff here...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works fine, its gets the data I want, but its slowww. Also, sometimes I get memory crashes if the file is over 2MB. Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe a way of getting the metadata without having to actually open the pdf file?

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: To increase speed, try to find another library:PDFBOX for example.Or parse/encrypt your data in another place of your app and set ready information to your listview

Comment: Your PdfReader object come from witch Library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try fast [PDFParse](https://github.com/agolinko/pdfparse) library. It optimized for performance & small memory consumption.

```
File[] filteredFiles = root.listFiles(filter);
for (int i=0;i<filteredFiles.length;i++) {
    try {                   
        File f = filteredFiles[i];                  
        PDFDocument reader = new PDFDocument(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String title = reader.getDocumentInfo().getTitle();
        reader.close();

        //Do other stuff here...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```